# New Feature Layer isn't showing up in Geodatabase

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, data-management

I've been using the following script to add a new layer to a geodatabase.

```
 arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
 in_features = "lease_polygon_testing"
 out_layer= "lease_polygon_testing_Layer3"
 where_clause="Created_On > CURRENT_DATE - 830"
 arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features,
                              out_layer,
                              where_clause,)
 arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(out_layer, 
 "X:/UserFolders/AnneGilligan/WC_74_Testing/landtrac_lease_test.gdb")
```

The script returns the exit code 0, however, I cannot find the layer in the geodatabase.

Comment: You're not passing an output feature class name to CopyFeatures; you're only passing a path to a geodatabase. Try something like: `arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(out_layer, 
 "X:/UserFolders/AnneGilligan/WC_74_Testing/landtrac_lease_test.gdb/MyOutputFC")`

Comment: I notice that this was the issue as well, but I was still getting errors. I tried creating a model in arcmap and exporting the script. I think something is corrupt in my GDB because it works on a new one I created, but not on the GDB I was using for testing.

Comment: if you had run the script that is in your post, it may have corrupted the gdb.